# is there a difference between <element/> and <element></element> in XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsd-validation

In an XML file, I need to send the value of an element as "nil", does having the tag as the following `<element/>` and `<element></element>` one and the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between `<element/>` and `<element></element>`, both are markup for an empty `element` element. As for XSD, if you want to create a nil valued element, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils, you need `<element xsi:nil="true"/>` respectively `<element xsi:nil="true"></element>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I will have a check.